# System.Nullable<T> What is the value of null * int value?

Tags: c#, null, operators, nullable, lifted-operators

Consider the following statements:

```
int? v1 = null;

int? v2 = 5 * v1;
```

What is the value of  `v2`? (`null` or empty string?)

How can I prevent the compiler to mark it as invalid operation? Do I need to follow custom exception handling?

Comment: How can that be an empty string?

Comment: @Kobi It certainly cannot. Maybe the asker was writing out the `v2` value somehow, and then it may become apparent that `v2.ToString() == ""`. The `Nullable<>` type overrides `ToString` and outputs `""` if `HasValue` is false. Note: This is relevant only if `ToString` is called directly, without boxing `v2` first (for example `IFormattable box = v2` will give a `null` reference, not a box; so `box.ToString("D4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will fail, trying to follow a `null` reference).

Comment: @Jeppe - Good point about `Nullable` and it's edge cases with `ToString` - I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's `null`.

> #### C# Language Specification 3.0 (Section §7.2.7: Lifted operators)
>
> For the binary operators `+`  `-`  `*`  `/`  `%`  `&`  `|`  `^`  `<<` `>>` :
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types are all non-nullable value types. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand and result type. **The lifted operator produces a `null` value if one or both operands are `null`** (an exception being the `&` and `|` operators of the `bool?` type, as described in §7.10.3). Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands, applies the underlying operator, and wraps the result.

---

> How can I prevent the compiler to mark it as invalid operation? Do I need to follow custom exception handling?

It's not an invalid operation. It won't throw an exception so you don't need to handle exceptions in this case.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad for detailed expln.

Answer (score 11):

If you want the operation to be prevented by the compiler, make the second variable non-nullable.  Then you will be forced to write:

```
int v2 = 5 * v1.Value;
```

This will throw an exception at run time if v1 is null.

Answer (score 1):

Its value will be "null", in this context at least can be considered to be the same as a database null, i.e. rather than Nothing, or Zero, it means "Unknown". Five lots of Unknown is still Unknown, it'll also never be "empty string" as you're dealing with numbers, not strings.

I'm not sure what you mean by "How can I prevent the compiler to mark it as invalid operation?" as this code compiles and runs fine for me under Visual Studio 2008 =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want v2 to be null if v1 is null then you should test if v1 has a value prior to using it.

```
int? v2 = v1.HasValue ? 5 * v1.Value : null;
```

or

```
int? v2 = null;
if (v1.HasValue) { v2 = 5 * v1.Value; }
```

Comment: This is not true. You can simply multiply and achieve the same results.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I don't think I said otherwise. I was just indicating that you can and normally should test if the nullable value has a value before using said value.