# Why nullable int (int?) doesn't increase the value via "+=" if the value is NULL?

Tags: c#, operators, nullable

I have a page counter type of int?:

```
spot.ViewCount += 1;
```

It works ONLY if the value of ViewCount property is **NOT NULL** (any int).

Why the compiler do so?

I would be grateful for any solutions.

Comment: What do you think `NULL+1` should be?

Comment: I believe the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327917/system-nullablet-what-is-the-value-of-null-int-value?rq=1 pretty much answers this question.

Comment: To  wudzik: Year! You are right - nothing... Thanks

Comment: @Kamil Budziewski: I would expect an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'll look into what compiler has produced for you then you'll see the internal logic behind.

The code:

```
int? i = null;
i += 1;
```

Is actually threated like:

```
int? nullable;
int? i = null;
int? nullable1 = i;
if (nullable1.HasValue)
{
    nullable = new int?(nullable1.GetValueOrDefault() + 1);
}
else
{
    int? nullable2 = null;
    nullable = nullable2;
}
i = nullable;
```

*I used JustDecompile to get this code*

Answer (score 12):

`Null` is not the same as `0`. Therefore, there's no logical operation that will increase null to an int value (or any other value type). If you want to increase the value of a nullable int from null to `1`, for example, you could do this.

```
int? myInt = null;
myInt = myInt.HasValue ? myInt += 1 : myInt = 1;

//above can be shortened to the below which uses the null coalescing operator ??
//myInt = ++myInt ?? 1
```

(although remember that this isn't increasing `null`, it's just achieving the effect of assigning an integer to a nullable int value when it's set as null).

Comment: what about `myInt = ++myInt ?? 1`

Comment: I was just trying to be explicit about the `HasValue` aspect but you're right, that would be even nicer :)

Answer (score 4):

Because nullable types [have lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean). Generally, [it's a specific case of function lifting](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting) in C# (or at least it looks like it is, correct me if I'm wrong).

Which means that any operation with `null` will have a `null` result (e.g `1 + null`, `null * null` etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this **extension method**:

```
public static int? Add(this int? num1, int? num2)
{
    return num1.GetValueOrDefault() + num2.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
spot.ViewCount = spot.ViewCount.Add(1);
```

Or even:

```
int? num2 = 2; // or null
spot.ViewCount = spot.ViewCount.Add(num2);
```

Comment: You don't need to write a custom extension method to get a nullable's value, or it's default value if there is no value.  `Nullable` already has that method, `GetValueOrDefault`.

Comment: @Serv Good point, I changed it. However, defining another extension method is not a mistake and especially not deserve a down vote.